# Specializing some methods in template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a class which has a template specialization version. However, the former can't see the method implemented by the generic version.
How can I make all methods in the generic version visible by the 
specialized version?

For example:

**test.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A_base{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class A : public A_base<T> {
public:
    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "foo: generic type" << "\n";
    }
};

template <>
class A<int> : public A_base<int>{
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar: int type" << "\n";
    }
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.hpp"

int main(){
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(); // expected "foo: generic type"
    a.bar(); // expected "bar: int type"
}
```

Why `A<int> a` can't see `foo()`?

Comment: Because a specialisation is completely independent of the template it is specialising. This means more work in cases like these, but also allows for greater flexibility in other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `A<int>` a can't see `foo()`?

By specializing the class template `A<T>` for `T = int`, you are defining how the class template `A<T>` is when `T` corresponds to `int`, and that specialization (i.e.: `A<int>`) you are providing has **no** member called `foo` (the primary template however does).

It is possible to individually specialize the member functions of a class template. So, you can simply specialize the member function `bar` of the class template `T` for `T = int` instead of doing it for the whole class template:

```
template <>
void A<int>::bar(){
        std::cout << "bar: int type" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I understand why this alternative works, but I don't understand why should I have to redefine every method of the generic version in the partially specialized version in order to make it work.

Comment: @DanielSaad Think of specializing the class template for a given type like "redefining" the class for just that type.

Comment: Okay, but it seems very counter-intuitive to me. Maybe i should place the generic code in the base class.

Comment: @DanielSaad Imagine that one of the member functions of your class template makes use of a certain operation for the generic type `T`, but this operation is not available for `int`'s. Then you can specialize that template class for `int` and without defining that member function.

Comment: @DanielSaad also when you want to provide an additional member function that only makes sense for a particular type. Then, you specialize the class template for that particular type and write the implementation of that additional member function which is not part of the primary template. Bear in mind, for example, that `std::strings`'s and `int` are quite different.

Comment: Interesting specializations in the standard library would be `std::vector<bool>` and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`